# How to close multiple modals on one page

Tags: javascript, wordpress, dialog, modal-dialog

Please see this link for reference: http://acue.siteassembly.com/cmf2/

If you scroll down on the page and hover over any of the profile boxes then click "Read More" you will see a modal popup. The trouble I'm having is in enabling multiple modals on one page, closing each modal, respectively, etc.

Here's one example of the HTML (Exported from WordPress Template). Each modal has its own html, in sequential order, as outlined in the JS below.

```
<!-- Begin Padron Modal -->

<div id="cmModalContainer">
<div id="cmModal">
<div class="close">×</div>
<p><img src="https://siteassembly.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/eduardo-padron-square-headshot.png" alt="Eduardo Padrón Headshot" /></p>
<div class="modal-content-wrap">
<h1 class="faculty-modal-title">Eduardo Padrón</h1>
<ul>
    <li class="title1"><p>President, Miami Dade College</p></li>
    <li class="title2"><p>Member, ACUE Board of Advisors</p></li>
</ul>
<div class="grey-line-divider"></div>
<p class="modal-article article-top">Today, higher education is confronted by enormous challenges. Our enduring charge is student learning—the cultivation of deep understanding and the capacity to apply new knowledge. But our enterprise is more complex than ever. Technology’s constant evolution, increased student diversity, and the transformation of our workforce all demand new responses.
<br /><br />
We have not lacked for effort. We’ve expanded advising and provide supplemental instruction. We monitor predictive analytics, intervene accordingly, and redesign courses to make pathways clear and coherent. We’re focusing on the first-year experience and asking students to collaborate on projects, conduct research, and learn through civic engagement.
<br /><br />
<div class="individual-quote">“If we are to meet the challenges of learning in this time of change, teaching must be central to our success.”</div>
<br /><br />
<p class="modal-article article-bottom">All of this is valuable and relevant but only part of what is required to significantly advance student success. Although the faculty of our colleges and universities possess distinguished content expertise and research acumen, too seldom have they been equipped with equivalent pedagogical skills and expertise. This is particularly relevant for our many non-tenure-track educators whose primary responsibility is to teach. If we are to meet the challenges of learning in this time of change, teaching must be central to our success.
<br /><br />
Toward this end, it is my privilege to work with the Association of College and University Educators (ACUE). ACUE’s Effective Practice Framework provides higher education with a much-needed common statement of the instructional skills and knowledge that every college educator should possess. ACUE’s online Course in Effective Teaching Practices is comprehensive and steeped in pedagogical research. The ACUE Certificate in Effective College Instruction is awarded in collaboration with the American Council on Education (ACE). And its Community of Professional Practice keeps faculty informed about the latest developments in teaching and allows them to collaborate with peers nationwide.
<br /><br />
ACUE’s work represents what few institutions could have built alone: a scalable and affordable program to make great teaching a strategic driver of student success. I serve on ACUE’s board of advisors and am inspired by the change that has been set in motion and believe that great teaching—a long-sought priority of higher education—is within our grasp.
<br /><br />
<strong style="font-size: 28px;">Exceeding Expectations</strong>
<br /><br />    
From the outset, ACUE adopted exacting design standards. Its course would be evidence-based and relevant to faculty regardless of discipline, years of experience, or level of instruction. As a primer in teaching foundations, it would be comprehensive and model, through its learning design, recommended practices. To support large numbers of faculty, it would also need to be scalable. Molly Corbett Broad, president of ACE from 2008 until September. 1, 2017, Linda Nilson, an expert on college instruction, and Catherine Haras, a leader in faculty development, discuss how these standards have been met.</p>
</p>
</div><!-- end modal-content-wrap -->
</div><!-- end cmModal -->
</div><!-- end cmModalContainer -->

<!-- End Padron Modal -->
```

Here's my JS

```
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('cmModalContainer');
var cmModalTwo = document.getElementById('cmModalContainerTwo');
var cmModalThree = document.getElementById('cmModalContainerThree');
var cmModalFour = document.getElementById('cmModalContainerFour');
var cmModalFive = document.getElementById('cmModalContainerFive');
var cmModalSix = document.getElementById('cmModalContainerSix');
var cmModalSeven = document.getElementById('cmModalContainerSeven');
var cmModalEight = document.getElementById('cmModalContainerEight');
var cmModalNine = document.getElementById('cmModalContainerNine');
var cmModalTen = document.getElementById('cmModalContainerTen');
var cmModalEleven = document.getElementById('cmModalContainerEleven');
var cmModalTwelve = document.getElementById('cmModalContainerTwelve');
var cmModalThirteen = document.getElementById('cmModalContainerThirteen');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById('cmModalBtn');
var btnTwo = document.getElementById('mollyBtn');
var btnThree = document.getElementById('lindaBtn');
var btnFour = document.getElementById('catherineBtn');
var btnFive = document.getElementById('danielBtn');
var btnSix = document.getElementById('aaronBtn');
var btnSeven = document.getElementById('kevinBtn');
var btnEight = document.getElementById('amyBtn');
var btnNine = document.getElementById('maryBtn');
var btnTen = document.getElementById('bonitaBtn');
var btnEleven = document.getElementById('lorettaBtn');
var btnTwelve = document.getElementById('deborahBtn');
var btnThirteen = document.getElementById('joselBtn');

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName('close')[0];
var spanTwo = document.getElementsByClassName('closeTwo')[0];
var spanThree = document.getElementsByClassName('closeThree')[0];
var spanFour = document.getElementsByClassName('closeFour')[0];
var spanFive = document.getElementsByClassName('closeFive')[0];
var spanSix = document.getElementsByClassName('closeSix')[0];
var spanSeven = document.getElementsByClassName('closeSeven')[0];
var spanEight = document.getElementsByClassName('closeEight')[0];
var spanNine = document.getElementsByClassName('closeNine')[0];
var spanTen = document.getElementsByClassName('closeTen')[0];
var spanEleven = document.getElementsByClassName('closeEleven')[0];
var spanTwelve = document.getElementsByClassName('closeTwelve')[0];
var spanThirteen = document.getElementsByClassName('closeThirteen')[0];

// When the user clicks on the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
}
btnTwo.onclick = function() {
    cmModalTwo.style.display = "block";
}
btnThree.onclick = function() {
    cmModalThree.style.display = "block";
}
btnFour.onclick = function() {
    cmModalFour.style.display = "block";
}
btnFive.onclick = function() {
    cmModalFive.style.display = "block";
}
btnSix.onclick = function() {
    cmModalSix.style.display = "block";
}
btnSeven.onclick = function() {
    cmModalSeven.style.display = "block";
}
btnEight.onclick = function() {
    cmModalEight.style.display = "block";
}
btnNine.onclick = function() {
    cmModalNine.style.display = "block";
}
btnTen.onclick = function() {
    cmModalTen.style.display = "block";
}
btnEleven.onclick = function() {
    cmModalEleven.style.display = "block";
}
btnTwelve.onclick = function() {
    cmModalTwelve.style.display = "block";
}
btnThirteen.onclick = function() {
    cmModalThirteen.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}
spanTwo.onclick = function() {
    cmModalTwo.style.display = "none";
}
spanThree.onclick = function() {
    cmModalThree.style.display = "none";
}
spanFour.onclick = function() {
    cmModalFour.style.display = "none";
}
spanFive.onclick = function() {
    cmModalFive.style.display = "none";
}
spanSix.onclick = function() {
    cmModalSix.style.display = "none";
}
spanSeven.onclick = function() {
    cmModalSeven.style.display = "none";
}
spanEight.onclick = function() {
    cmModalEight.style.display = "none";
}
spanNine.onclick = function() {
    cmModalNine.style.display = "none";
}
spanTen.onclick = function() {
    cmModalTen.style.display = "none";
}
spanEleven.onclick = function() {
    cmModalEleven.style.display = "none";
}
spanTwelve.onclick = function() {
    cmModalTwelve.style.display = "none";
}
spanThirteen.onclick = function() {
    cmModalThirteen.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of a modal, close that modal
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
    if (event.target == cmModalTwo) {
        cmModalTwo.style.display = "none";
    }
    if (event.target == cmModalThree) {
        cmModalThree.style.display = "none";
    }
    if (event.target == cmModalFour) {
        cmModalFour.style.display = "none";
    }
    if (event.target == cmModalFive) {
        cmModalFive.style.display = "none";
    }
    if (event.target == cmModalSix) {
        cmModalSix.style.display = "none";
    }
    if (event.target == cmModalSeven) {
        cmModalSeven.style.display = "none";
    }
    if (event.target == cmModalEight) {
        cmModalEight.style.display = "none";
    }
    if (event.target == cmModalNine) {
        cmModalNine.style.display = "none";
    }
    if (event.target == cmModalTen) {
        cmModalTen.style.display = "none";
    }
    if (event.target == cmModalEleven) {
        cmModalEleven.style.display = "none";
    }
    if (event.target == cmModalTwelve) {
        cmModalTwelve.style.display = "none";
    }
    if (event.target == cmModalThirteen) {
        cmModalThirteen.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like your function that's intended to close a modal when a visitor clicks outside it is actually set to hide the modal when a visitor clicks inside it. If the click event target equals the modal, you are setting the modal to display none. So, you need to change that whole section - if the event target is not equal to any of the modals, then set all of the modals to display none.

Comment: Unfortunately, that did not resolve the issue. I appreciate the feedback, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy way to tackle this is with Bootstrap's modal. I've made a simple jsfiddle for you here: https://jsfiddle.net/maxbilbow/0Ld36bxk/7/

I can see on your site that the jQuery libraries are already included so you just need to add the [bootstrap js and css files](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/getting-started/) to that page:

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

This will handle all of the boilerplate code while allowing you to customise the design.